# Ubuntu WiFi issues on Compaq Presario M2000

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wifi-driver, compaq-laptop

I Have a friend who's installed Ubuntu 10 on his ageing Compaq Presario
M2000 and its all working as it should other than the inbuilt WiFi. I've tried looking at the Compaq support page but to no avail. Anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to install the NDIS (Windows XP) drivers.

Install the *"Windows Wireless Drivers"* package and then use that to install the Windows XP drivers.

Answer (score 0):

I posted a similar answer here:

[How come I cant connect to wireless on ubuntu but mac is ok?](https://superuser.com/questions/265734/how-come-i-cant-connect-to-wireless-on-ubuntu-but-mac-is-ok/265748#265748)

Here's a brief copy-paste summary of that:

Try this first:

`Administration->Additional Drivers`.  This is the simplest solution (if there is one available).

If this doesn't work, you'll have to find a solution specific to your hardware. You can find out the type of card you have by running `sudo lshw -C network`.

If you plug the product name into Google (or another search engine) with the keyword ubuntu, you should be able to find a post on the Ubuntu forums. If you can't find anything, then post the wireless product you have.